# Chat events starting in the past show as starting in the future

Tags: bug, chat, timestamps, chat-event

The following screenshot, taken 37 minutes after the start of a chat event, says it all:

[image]

The event "Comic Book Recommendations" was scheduled to start 37 minutes *before* this picture was taken (as confirmed by the "Upcoming events" list at the top), but on the room itself the event is listed as starting "in 37m", which sounds like it means 37 minutes *after* the picture was taken.

**This is *not* simply a caching problem.** I was refreshing this page multiple times in quick succession just around the time the event began, and watched the countdown change from "in 41s" to "in 21s" to "in 4s" to "in 4s" to "in 13s" to "in 28s" to "in 45s". The count went *down and then up again* while keeping the same wording of "in X seconds", which seems weird and buggy.

This problem continued to be visible for several hours after the event: 3 hours after the start of the event, it was listed as "in 3h" on the rooms overview.

Comment: Bug is still present in 2019: https://i.imgur.com/MguJ0Bj.png